# Gretl - test alpha and beta

Tags: statistics, regression-testing, gretl

I have done an ordinary least squared with an excel data set. Now I want to test α against the value of 0 and β against the value of 1 using an error probability of 0.05%.

How to do this in gretl?

I appreciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit your post to add a gretl flag, hope we'll have more gretl users in SO too.

Now to answer to your question, you need to deal with general linear restriction in your model and computing the related F-test.

So to do it with gretl, you can do something like this using gretl scripting language hansl :

```
open murder_rates
ols executions const income lfp southern --quiet

restrict
b[income]=0
b[lfp]=1
end restrict
```

And we have the following result

```
## Restriction set
##  1: b[income] = 0
##  2: b[lfp] = 1

## Test statistic: F(2, 41) = 29633.7, with p-value = 1.6337e-65

## Restricted estimates:

##              coefficient   std. error   t-ratio    p-value 
##   ---------------------------------------------------------
##   const       -53.0056      0.370949    -142.9     3.29e-59 ***
##   income        0.00000     0.00000       NA      NA       
##   lfp           1.00000     0.00000       NA      NA       

##   Standard error of the regression = 2.4606
```

If you want to do it with easily with R check the `car` package (`linearHypothesis` function)

Comment: Thx you very much for your answer!!! Is there also a solution where I can use the gretl IDE? what is `b[income]=0` in your model? Would it look like `b=1` for \beta = 1 and `a=1` for \alpha = 0? How to take directly the coefficience names? I really appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: If your coef are named beta and alpha, it will be `b[beta]=1` and `b[alpha]=0`. You can subscript using number too. So `b` is not for the variable `b` but is to access all coefficient from your model.